# Update grid row within a grid using a datasource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, runtime-error, sqldatasource

I might be posting tons of ASP.NET questions during the coming weeks because the place I'm working at during the summer gives me several things to add to their CRM system even though I have never worked with ASP.NET or Microsoft SQL, only PHP & MySQL. So here's a question for you guys.

I have this gridview which is loading it's data from the datasourceid *objOffices*. I've read somewhere that you cant use a  button or even the grid-updating functionality when loading your data to a grid using datasource. I would not like to use templates if there's a way around them as I want as few lines as possible.

So the question is; **How would I update a row in a gridview which uses a datasource to fetch it's data without templates?**

I highly appreciate your answers. Have a great day!

**EDIT:**
Here are two pictures of the grid in action using a commandfield with *ShowEditButton* set to true.

[image: When not editing, this is the default view.]

[image: When editing, this is what it looks like.]

And when there are more offices added, there'll be more rows obviously.

**EDIT 2:**
Here's the code for the gridview;

http://pastebin.com/F1pTmFzT

**EDIT 3:**
This is the error I get when pressing update on the row;

[image: Error when pressing the 'update' button on a row.]

Comment: You mean update, as in edit the data in the datasource, commit them to the database? Or do you want to manipulate the appearance?

Comment: @Alexander I both wish to manipulate the appearance and update the row in the database. But as long I figure out or get help on how to set up the events and such I can figure out the rest in no-time. Thanks!

Comment: We'll need more input then, Magnus. Depending on what layout you want, the GridView might not even be the control of choice. Give us a sketch of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of input. I've added two pictures now which I hope will be useful for you. @Alexander

Comment: And what happens when you edit data and hit Update? (Except for the ID, of course.)

Comment: Can I get back to you tomorrow? I just came home and can't access the files from here. Thanks for helping me! @Alexander

Comment: @Alexander Added a print of the error..

Comment: Now read that error message, and then take a look at ObjectDataSource "objOffices". What do you see? If you don't see anything, show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Thanks for guiding me in the right direction, Alexander - Instead of using *UpdateMethod="x"* in the gridview I used it in the DataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objOffices" runat="server" SelectMethod="AdminCustomerGetCustomerOffices"
TypeName="FAQServer" UpdateMethod="updateOffices"> // <-- HERE!
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CUS_Id" QueryStringField="CUS_Id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

It's fully working now with no errors in sight, thanks to Alexander for helping me out!